# SOQL OrderBy Account Name implications

Tags: soql

I'm trying to develop a on type search component on Account object and stumbled upon using this query

```
SELECT Name
FROM Account
ORDER BY Name DESC NULLS LAST
```

As you can see from the above query I'm ordering by Name field. My question is Name(Indexed) field on Account is always required so does it have any negative effects doing `DESC NULLS LAST` if the volume of Account records in my org is higher say 1 million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're filtering your query, the NULLS (FIRST|LAST) operator won't have any negative side effects. Just remember to filter/limit your query, and you'll be fine.

Comment: I'm actually using that plain query without any filters.By your answer above I think I'd run into issues

Comment: @saikumar Yes, remember that you've got a 50k row governor limit. You can't just load a million records into your component, it won't work very well. Keep it under some reasonable value like 50 or 100.